# How to manipulate structure (array inside)?

Tags: c#, arrays, structure

This is the structure:

```
public struct ProfilePoint
{
    public double x;
    public double z;
    byte intensity;
}
```

It is used inside a callback function (I deleted most of it so it won't make sense, there is a for loop that cycle through every points (arrayIndex) that were scanned on a surface and process them. The result is stored inside profileBuffer):

```
   public static void onData(KObject data)
            {
               if (points[arrayIndex].x != -32768)
                                        {
                                            profileBuffer[arrayIndex].x = 34334;
                                            profileBuffer[arrayIndex].z = 34343;
                                         validPointCount++;
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            profileBuffer[arrayIndex].x = 32768;
                                            profileBuffer[arrayIndex].z = 32768;
                                        }
                                    }             
                                }
```

I would like to process the data inside profileBuffer (both array, x & z).

So far I was "able" to create a function that get one value from profileBuffer with no error from visual studio:

```
public static int ProcessProfile(double dataProfile)
{
    int test=1;

    return test;
}
```

Putting this line:

```
ProcessProfile(profileBuffer[1].x);
```

Into onData() result in no error but that's just one value. Ideally, I would like to have the whole array. What confuse me is that every value stored inside profileBuffer are double (forget intensity). But stored in array. Yet I can't import the data like ProcessProfile(profileBuffer.x); I have to specify an index... Is it possible to manipulate a vector (line) of data? That would be ideal for me.

Sorry for the poor explanation / long post... I am quite newb.

Comment: Do you just need a `foreach` loop? Try Googling that

Comment: `ProfileBuffer` is an array in your case or some collection, so you have to index it or get the item and then call `.x` on it. `x` is not a property or field of your collection so you wouldn't be able to call `profileBuffer.x`

Comment: And yes your question is not clear as to what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
public static int ProcessProfile(ProfilePoint []points)
{
     var x = points[4].x;
.....
}
```

and do

```
ProcessProfile(profileBuffer);
```